# Build a tableview form and print in Swift 3

Tags: swift, forms, printing, tableview, segue

I am trying to build a form for a friend. I've tried doing tableviews, but doing so all the sub pages will have different info to fill in. So I wasn't sure if the best way to do this Is by building each page inside form different and not as a tableview. However way I go about this the print button only shows up once all pages have been filled

Questions I have:

1. Is it difficult to print all three pages info from AirPrint?
2. What is the best way to build this? Is it still tableviews?
3. If not using route of tableviews how do I add up the empty text boxes to bring back a percentage bar?
4. My first page I have set up is a tableview, if that is the way to do that how can I make a separate view for each row?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to build a form I would suggest using the library found here: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka. The library includes a lot of different types of fields and validations for different data types.

In order to create an action from selecting a button you can use the onCellSelection callback like this:

```
 +++ Section()
                <<< ButtonRow() {
                    $0.title = "Tap to force form validation"
                }
                .onCellSelection { cell, row in
                   
                   //Do something here once the row has been tapped
                }
```

Comment: thanks I will check that out! I'm just trying to figure out if tableviews are going to get the job done better than bringing a lot of labels and textfields out

Comment: Yes forms are created using tableviews. The Eureka library uses a FormViewController and allows you to add each field. If you have multiple forms, you can create multiple FormViewControllers and link them together.

Comment: That Eureka is very nice! I still have a few questions. At the top I revised current screenshots. how do I get the uitableview rows to link up to different view controllers. and inside eurekas code is there a way to take for example Childs full name and make that a push row to have the first name middle and last inside as textrows? the problem is I have so many fields that in the simulator it doesn't show all when trying to scroll

Comment: @BlueMoose I updated my answer on how to do something after selecting a row. I do not know what you mean with your second question. If this has been helpful please accept my answer so others can see it. For further questions, please open up another question.